# Using require.js and Asynchronous Module Definition (AMD) possible in a Symfony2 project?

Tags: javascript, rest, symfony, requirejs, amd

I'm currently modernizing my workflow especially in the frontend part and started using [require.js](http://requirejs.org), [qunit](http://qunitjs.com/), [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/), etc. in some of my last project that didn't require a backend.

Coming from Symfony2 I'm used to normally write my templates in Twig and have Assetic make all the necessary magic like js/css minification, assets, etc. [Research shows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10523273/how-to-use-assetic-for-requirejs) that Assetic isn't currently capable of serving javascript files the way require.js needs them.

Now I really like the idea behind RequireJS, [Asynchronous Module Definition](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html) (AMD) and was wondering how I could profit from its awesomeness in a Symfony2 project. The most sensible approach imho would be to reduce the Symfony2 project to simply serve necessary data, e.g. by providing RESTful interfaces. This would furthermore result in a complete decoupled frontend <> backend that could be developed and tested more independently.

My question is: Wouldn't I lose some of the goodies Symfony2 gives me like the complete form handling (CSRF protection, validation, etc.) and security? Has anyone done this already and is able to share some insights? Are there some drawbacks/pitfalls to look for? And…is it worth it? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my master twig template I defined (e.g. {% block js %}) the javascript section like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    getCoreBundleName: function() {
        return 'openframeworkcore';
    },
    getPath: function(bundleName, filePath) {
        return bundleName + '/components/' + filePath;
    },
    getCorePath: function(filePath) {
        return this.getPath(this.getCoreBundleName(), filePath);
    }
};

require.config({
    baseUrl: '{{ app.request.getBasePath() }}/bundles/',
    paths: {
        core: 'openframeworkcore/core/js/core',
        bootstrap: config.getCorePath('bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap')
    },
    shim: {
        bootstrap: {
            deps: ['jquery']
        },
        fancybox: {
            deps: ['jquery', 'jquery-mousewheel']
        },
        angular: {
            exports: 'angular'
        },
        restangular: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'angular']
        },
        'jquery-ui': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
});

// loads the core.js
require(['core']);
</script>
```

Im my case I used restangular. A framework that extends angularjs with rest methods.
But it only provides some helper method to communicate restful.

On the other hand you restangular work perfect together with Symfony2

```
/**
 * @Route("/create")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 * @Template()
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $form = $this->createForm(new BoardType());

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView()
    );
}
```

I've already combine requirejs with Symfony2
For further question not hesitate to ask me.

Cheers

Comment: Your solution sounds really promising. What about minification? Can you still do that via assetic?

Comment: Hi nietonfir. I'm still working on a one file solution. This document http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html explains the mechanism. I think you have to use r.js

Comment: Thx for the heads-up anyways! I'll accept your answer as you provided very nice insights. ;-)

Comment: Thank you :) I bookmarked this page to inform you about any updates

Answer (score 1):

We are currently in the midst of rewriting our intranet app based upon our own RESTful framework, which uses Twig and jQuery, as we were disappointed with various aspects of existing frameworks such as [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/), [Tonic](http://www.peej.co.uk/tonic/) and Recess.

We've found that it was fairly trivial to integrate things like declarative form field validation (each PHP class responsible for a class of HTTP resources declares which form fields have what validation requirements, and the REST framework enforces these in the received data) and native JSON-HAL export (our PHP objects are HAL-formatted, HAL export is simply a `json_encode()` call).

There was about one man-month of development put into the REST framework (including evaluating other frameworks). Whether you would consider that "worth it" or not depends on how critical the system is to your business :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [Hearsay\RequireJSBundle](https://github.com/hearsayit/HearsayRequireJSBundle). It integrates Require.js with Assetic and allows you to configure Require.js using the Symfony2 configuration system.